# Replace text in latex but leave markup and math untouched

Tags: text, copyright

I need to replace text in a book with a symbol. I'm not allowed to change anything in the sources. This must be an external application. For example,

```
\section[First]{First}\label{first}
Hell\"o this is a first section.
$$A = 0$$
```

Needs to be replaced with this

```
\section[First]{First}\label{first}
????\"? ???? ?? ? ????? ????????
$$A = 0$$
```

Is there something to help me with this? Maybe not exactly this but close to this? It can be ready made code or some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Not at all sure what you are after. Perhaps something along the lines:

```
\newcommand{\secintro}[1]{%
  ????\"? ???? ?? ? ????? ???????? \\
#1}

\section[First]{First]\label{first}
\secintro{$$A = 0$$}
```

If this helps you please indicate this on the Answer, otherwise post a comment about why it does not.

Comment: I have a sources. And I need to replace all text with some symbol (? or some other). I can use C#/Python/C++ or any other language for this. I'm not allowed to change anything in the tex-files.

Comment: In that case, I'm not seeing how TeX is really related to the question.  This seems to be more of a text processing question, and not really on topic for this site.

Comment: @Yola I'm really confused. You say that to need to change the TeX code from "this" to "that" but you are not allowed to change anything in the TeX files!